# listen to keystrokes from different pages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background-process

I want to develop an extension that runs in the background and listens to keystrokes and stores them as a string in a variable. For example, if I have 5 tabs in a chrome browser window and I press a,b,c,d,e on each tab of the window; the final string should be abcde.

Could any please provide a sample code for this?

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add code like this to a content script:

```
var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
bodyElement.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
    console.log(e);
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
});
```

The body element must be loaded for this code to work, so use jQuery's $(document).ready(), or similar, or in the extension manifest set the run_at value for the script to document_end.